# android tableLayout on a custom dialog

Tags: java, android

I am using a custom dialog from my customdialog.xml that contains a tableLayout filled with row.xml. Normaly this code works on an activity class but, as a dialog, when I add a tableLayout and insert a row, app crashes. How to reach it?

Code:

```
private void customDialog(){

        // custom dialog
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);


                    TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textNom)).setText("testing...");

                    TableLayout llistaLlistes = (TableLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.llistaLlistes);

                    llistaLlistes.addView(row);

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();

    }
```

crash log:

```
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appdev.stpro/com.appdev.stpro.StPROActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.appdev.stpro.StPROActivity.customDialog(StockPROActivity.java:236)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at com.appdev.stpro.StPROActivity.onCreate(StockPROActivity.java:212)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-25 18:39:57.509: E/AndroidRuntime(27839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
```

if layout is necessary please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always go the otherwa around

Create a class and xml for your tablelayout. 
then in the android manifest add this on the activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

now just get the onclicklistener to start the activity instead of the dialog!

Comment: mmm sure! I like this option. Then you can handle result calling startActivityForResult(). This is totally flexible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had some kind of problems when i tried to programmaticaly add row to a table accordingly to a datatab.

I managed to do it with horizontal linear layout created in a loop instead of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs in Android work differently than dialogs in core Java. You should extend DialogFragments to create custom layouts. The Android Dialog Design Guide shows you how to do dialogs with custom layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout